# What does this Amazon echo light indicator mean?

Tags: amazon-echo

My echo keeps showing this indicator. It goes on for a long while, stops some time later, but then I notice it's happening again.

[image: enter image description]

Answer (score 2):

**Cyan on blue**

What it means:

A cyan spotlight on a blue ring means that Alexa is listening.

The light ring glimmers briefly when Alexa has heard and is processing your request. A briefly glimmering blue light might also mean the device is receiving a software update.

Check the link for a complete description of different led patterns:

https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=GKLDRFT7FP4FZE56